# error : Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php, html5

Hay forma de enviar una variable desde la primera vista de un login?

el error desaparece cuando en el algún href coloco las variables, ejemplo: **joel/login/index.php?hoja=&error=**. El problema es cuando ingreso en la primera vista donde la url es: **joel/login/**. Sin embargo se muestra el login a la vista pero con los errores.

[image]

Hay forma de hacer que al darle click en la carpeta **/login/** me envíe automaticamente las varibles "hoja" y "error" en la URL? Oh en otros casos que se forme esta URL: **joel/login/?hoja=&error=**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando las variables están en la URL, todo error desaparece como en la imágen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código **PHP** que tengo dentro del login es:

```
<?php

                    $a1 = $_GET['hoja'];

                    if(empty($a1)){

                    }else{

                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>FELICITACIONES!!</strong><br>Tus datos se han registrado correctamente, ahora puedes <i>Iniciar Sesión</i></div>';

                    }

                    $a2 = $_GET['error'];

                    if(($a2)){

                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>LO SENTIMOS!!</strong><br>El nombre de Usuario y/o contraseña no existen o son incorrectos, intenta de nuevo</div>';

                    }
                
                    ?>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer dos cosas: 1) Modificar tu .htaccess agregando `Options -Indexes` en la primera línea para que no te muestre la estructura de carpetas. Y 2) crear un index.php en la raiz que te haga la redirección si no está logeado, y si lo está lo mande donde deba ir.

Comment: El problema es que asignas directamente `$_GET['hoja']` y después compruebas si está vacío. Podrías hacer `$a1 = $_GET['hoja'] ?? '';` y después hacer `if ($a1=='') {`. Y lo mismo con `$a2`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ambos comentarios me sirvieron, error solucionado ;)

Comment: Pon como respuesta lo que te ha sido útil, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.